# findind all using .all vs. where

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my controller i am getting all entries form a table like this

```
@enums = Enuemerations.all
```

Then later i want to search and get the name from by doing

```
@enums.find(107).name
```

I get an error

```
undefined method `name' for #<Enumerator:0xb5eb9d98>
```

So I tried it out in the rails console and found this working

```
Enumeration.where(false).find(107)
```

where this does not work

```
Enumeration.all.find(107)
```

Can someone explain to me how this works?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `Enumeration.all` instantly queries the database returning an `Array` with all the Enumeration records (if you only want a single record this would be very inefficient). It no longer knows about the ActiveRecord methods:

```
 > Enumeration.all.class
  Enumeration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "enumerations".* FROM "enumerations" 
 => Array
```

Calling `find` on an `Array` uses [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) which would need a different syntax, e.g:

```
enums = Enumeration.all
enum = enums.find { |e| e.id == 2 }
 => #<Enumeration id: 2, name: "...">
```

---

Using `Enumeration.where(false)` only returns a lazy `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it doesn't actually hit the database (yet), this allows you to chain extra ActiveRecord methods such as `find` in your example above.

```
> Enumeration.where(false).class
 => ActiveRecord::Relation 

> Enumeration.where(false).find(2)
  Enumeration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "enumerations".* FROM "enumerations" WHERE "enumerations"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Enumeration id: 2, name: "...">
```