# What is the difference between .where(nil) and .all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause

I have been using

```
Product.all
```

but a lot of code that I have been seeing is using

```
Product.where(nil)
```

when populating a variable. this [site](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/search-and-filter-rails-models-without-bloating-your-controller/) has an example that I found for using where(nil). I have searched through documentation and found where where(nil) replaced scoped but can't make heads or tails of what it does.

Comment: Both give the same query `SELECT 'products'.* FROM 'products'`, and that means that they have the same functionality that's selecting all records. we can also say that `where(nil)` means _where no conditions are being applied!_

Comment: So I don't need to go back though my code and change all to where(nil)?

Comment: I think you don't, take a look here. _Where -> Returns a new relation, which is the result of filtering the current relation according to the conditions in the arguments._ https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Comment: Makes sense. When I tested it, it all looked the same. That's why I figured I'd send it up the flagpole. Thanks!

Comment: `Product.all` is much more descriptive. I would strongly prefer that to `Product.where(nil)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there used to be a difference, but from Rails 4 there no longer is. This is because from Rails 4 `.all` returns a relation whereas it used to return an array. So previously:

```
Product.all
```

immediately fires a query to the database to return all records, which would get loaded into an array in memory. Basically you are telling Rails that you want the data NOW. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610942/findind-all-using-all-vs-where) for more info.

```
Product.where(nil)
```

creates a query (actually an [anonymous scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219528/activerecord-anonymous-scope) that returns an `ActiveRecord:Relation`).

The query will only execute when you try to access the data for it. Since it is a scope, you can chain other scopes (without hitting the database each time) and have the entire chain execute as one query when you access the data.

In the Justin Weiss article linked to in the question, we see this code:

```
def index
  @products = Product.where(nil) # creates an anonymous scope
  @products = @products.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @products = @products.location(params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
  @products = @products.starts_with(params[:starts_with]) if params[:starts_with].present?
end
```

That code will execute one database call when the index method ends and returns the data.

But if you changed the first line to:

```
@products = Product.all
```

that query would execute immediately. Then the scopes are added, and another query would fire when index method ends. This is more inefficient.

**EDIT**

I believe the database call would actually happen when you first try to access some data in @products (not when the index method ends). Eg. if you did @products.first then the query would execute.